# How to execute synchronously method asynchronously and wait for result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous, begininvoke

My application is hooked up to many external devices through TCP/IP protocol and COM ports. Main logic is in the `MainController` class (implemented as a finite state machine), which listens to signals from external devices and sends commands to them.

Whenever `MainController` receives an external signal it notifies GUI with an event, for example `OnSensor1Received`, `OnSensor2Received`,... so I can display an icon or message or whatever. Same logic applies for other direction - when `MainController` sends a signal to external device, an event is raised and something is displayed in GUI.

Until here all the communication is asynchronous (if this is the correct term?). That means I receive events and process them and I fire commands but never wait for the return in the same operation (you could say all methods for sending commands are void).

But now I have to add new device, which has only one public method `int Process(string input, out string output)`. The execution of the method can take up to a couple of seconds and in the meantime all other code is waiting - for example if during the execution of this method I get a signal from another external device, the GUI will be refreshed only after the blocking method `Write` executes. How can I make the `Write` method execute asynchronously so that the GUI would display all other signals in real time?

Code example, this is called somewhere in the `MainController` when I try to use the new device:

```
// Notify GUI that the blocking plugin was activated.
OnBlockingPluginActive(this, EventArgs.Empty);

string result;
// Here is the problem - during the execution of this method the GUI is not responding for other signals.
var status = blockingPlugin.Process(input, out result);
if (status == 0)
{
    // OK, notify GUI and fire a BlockingPluginOK command in finite state machine.
    OnBlockingPluginOK(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
else
{
    // Error, notify GUI and fire a BlockingPluginError command in finite state machine.
    OnBlockingPluginError(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Please also note that I am using .net 4.0 and cannot upgrade to 4.5, so no native support for async/await.

Comment: You van try this: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.16](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.16)

Comment: If you are still using .NET 4.0, just use Task.Factory.StartNew and use .ContinueWith

Comment: "a couple of seconds" is not reasonable behavior.  You can move the call into a worker thread but you'll just firehose it and still block.  Either that library is drastically borken or it is just not behaving correctly right now due to environmental issues.  You are not going to make it better by trying to work around the issue, do ping the author of the library for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old fashioned [Asynchronous delegate call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.100).aspx) via `BeginInvoke` / `EndInvoke` with `AsyncCallback` and captured variables:

```
// Notify GUI that the blocking plugin was activated.
OnBlockingPluginActive(this, EventArgs.Empty);

string result;
Func<int> processAsync = () => blockingPlugin.Process(input, out result);
processAsync.BeginInvoke(ar =>
{
    var status = processAsync.EndInvoke(ar);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        // OK, notify GUI and fire a BlockingPluginOK command in finite state machine.
        OnBlockingPluginOK(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
       // Error, notify GUI and fire a BlockingPluginError command in finite state machine.
       OnBlockingPluginError(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever MainController receives an external signal it notifies GUI with an event...
>
> ...
>
> Until here all the communication is asynchronous...

It's already asynchronous. It's just using events to notify completions rather than a `Task` or an `IObservable`. Plain events do make for messier consuming code (i.e., your code has to be spread over many methods and explicitly maintain its own state objects), but they are actually *asynchronous*.

> How can I make the `Write` method execute asynchronously so that the GUI would display all other signals in real time?

Well, you can't "make it run asynchronously" - not for a proper meaning of "asynchronously", anyway. Currently, the `Write` method blocks the calling thread (i.e., it's synchronous). There isn't a way to call the method that magically prevents it from blocking the calling thread (i.e., asynchronous).

However, you can use a technique I call "fake asynchrony". Essentially, the UI thread *pretends* the operation is asynchronous by executing it on a thread pool thread. The operation is still blocking, but it blocks a thread pool thread rather than the UI thread.

If you can use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), then you could write code like this:

```
try
{
  var result = await TaskEx.Run(() =>
  {
    string result;
    if (blockingPlugin.Process(input, out result) != 0)
      throw new Exception("Blocking plugin failed.");
    return result;
  });
  OnBlockingPluginOK(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
catch
{
  OnBlockingPluginError(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to do it old-school:

```
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  string result;
  if (blockingPlugin.Process(input, out result) != 0)
    throw new Exception("Blocking plugin failed.");
  return result;
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
task.ContinueWith(t => OnBlockingPluginOK(this, EventArgs.Empty),
    TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
    ui);
task.ContinueWith(t => OnBlockingPluginError(this, EventArgs.Empty),
    TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion,
    ui);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you comment on @Ivan Stoev's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38551022/113858)? I tried it first and it looks like it is working ok.

Comment: @sventevit: `BeginInvoke` will also use a thread pool thread; however, that code example will raise `OnBlockingPluginOK` and `OnBlockingPluginError` on a thread pool thread rather than the UI thread.

Comment: @sventevit: I would not normally say so.